# Send cookies with node-fetch to bing

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, node-fetch

I am trying to fetch bing search results with 50 searches per page. Simply editing the url to include "&count=50" doesn't work, and so I am sending a cookie to update the preference.

Right now I have:

```
const opts = {
    headers: {
      cookie: "SRCHHPGUSR; NRSLT=50",
    },
  };
const response = await fetch("https://www.bing.com/search?q=example", opts);
```

Which does not work. Any ideas on how to set the cookie, or another better way of achieving 50 results per page?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code provided is sufficient